# How to check , what the source library for some class ? java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, dependencies

I am using android studio.
in my project i use google play service classes. e.g :

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.Info;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesRepairableException;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
```

at the build.gradle file, under dependencies section, i'v deleted this line :

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.+'`

the problem that i still build and run the app normally . also android studio has reference to google play services. very strange. right ?

How do that happen ?

maybe there is a library that i am use and it's already has google play services .

so How to know the source library for those classes. thanks.

Comment: In Eclipse I believe you can select the class name and F3 it to see where it is loaded from

Comment: @Kon Same functionality is to hold the `Ctrl` key and click the class name :)

Comment: @Trobbins & Kon , thank you for your comments. unfortunately that doesn't help. because I already know that the source (it is google play service library ) but I am unable to find How googlePlayLibraray was is installed . so i want to know the source of googlePlayLibrary in my project.

Answer (score 0):

to check dependency tree, you can use gradle command:

```
gradle dependencies
```

or

```
gradlew dependencies
```

see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_gradle_command_line.html

### Help tasks

dependencies - Displays all dependencies declared in root project 'projectReports'.
dependencyInsight - Displays the insight into a specific dependency in root project 'projectReports'.

if you have sub project, you should use:

```
gradle subProjectName:dependencies
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. i will check if that will help me.